# SQLBulkCopy inquiries

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, sqlbulkcopy

So I have a situation where I wrote a custom data table that is the result of an aggregation of multiple tables from multiple servers.  I take data from 2 different tables in Oracle 8.1x and a few more from SQL Server 2000, do some calculations and put the results on a new destination table in SQL Server 2008.  The initial results were great and the data came out correctly calculated, as seen through testing.  When I wrote the C# code to do all this, I had no choice but to use OleDb connections with Oracle and SQL 2000.  But on the destination server I could use SQLBulkCopy on the 2008.  SQL Bulk Copy works great and the program runs reasonably fast.  However since my tables look great they want me to put the destinations back on the SQL 2000 server using my code.

The problem is I am not sure if SQLBulkCopy will work on SQL 2000 since I can't use SQLConnections.  I have been trying to find an OleDb version of Bulk Copy that works in C# but so far all I can do is a 
    foreach(DataRow row in destination.Rows())
    {
        /* Insert one row at a time */
    }
Which is very slow since there are over 200,000 rows with several columns (the performance drops by a quite a bit).

So my questions are, will SQLBulkCopy work with SQL 2000, if not then is there a OleDb connection version, or do I have no choice but to use the slower one row at a time method.  6 months from now they do want it to go to SQL 2012, but for now they need it on SQL server 2000.

And thanks for any help or tips.

Comment: Looks like using the SQLBulkCopy won't work with SQL 2000, but you could try to just write a textfile, then suck it in with bcp. It may or may not be faster. You could also play around with Bulk Copy in DTS https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933512(v=sql.80).aspx.

Comment: sqlbulkcopy does not work with SQL2000 and any other database like oracle, access or excel as destination. As destination you can have only SQL 2005 or greater version. However for source you can use it http://dotnetmentors.com/c-sharp/bulk-upload-into-sql-server-using-sqlbulkcopy-and-c-sharp.aspx